# How to show different tables in different worksheet of excel based on parameters in SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which has two tables(one has X information and other has Y information). I want to show these tables in different worksheets of excel based on the parameter selection.

This parameter has multiple values, some which belong to **X** and others to **Y**.

Possible required outputs;-

1. if we select only X related vales in the parameter, then only single X table should be shown in excel(single worksheet).
2. if we select only Y related vales in the parameter, then only single Y table should be shown in excel(single worksheet).
3. When we select both X and Y values, then two different worksheets with their respective X and Y tables should be shown.

I have tried page breaks between the tables but on single selections they create extra worksheets.

Please suggest if this can be achieved.
Thanks

Comment: When you have tables that you may want to show, use the Visibility/Hidden property to show/hide based on your parameters selected with the page break at the END of the first table. You may need to put them in a Rectangle to prevent extra page breaks.

Comment: Thank You, It is working now.